# Read variable line by line in shell (dash included)

Tags: shell, sh

I have a variable with stored logs. What I want is to read every line of the variable containing logs and keep that line or remove base on some filtering stuff.

The problem is that my code is working on bash, but not working on the dash.

this is my code:

```
filtered_logs=""
while IFS= read -r line
do
 ...(store line to $filterered_logs if it comes throught filter )
done <<< "$logs"
logs="$filtered_logs"
```

this code is working in bash. But ' *done  <<< "$logs"* ' is not working in dash (since is default sh in ubuntu). It's homework and I need, that it works on every shell possible.

What i tried was:

```
filtered_logs=""
echo "$logs" |
while IFS= read -r line
do
 ...(store line to $filterered_logs if it comes throught filter )
done
logs="$filtered_logs"
```

But if I store something in from while cycle to $filtered_logs, it's not working. And I can't access this while cycling with my debugger too. (I think that the whole while cycle is a whole new process since I run it with |.

My question is how to make it works, please. Thank you

Comment: `man echo` ; `man cat` ; google "shell input redirection"

Comment: Every shell possible seems a to an unlimited assignment. Do you need to use the while-construction or can you switch to `awk`,  `sed` or another tool avoiding `while` (which has more problems like performance and skipping the last line when it is not ending with a newline) ?

Comment: yes, i can use both awk and sed. And it seems that other classmates used that. Sadly i didn't learned how to work with that, so i ended with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to use clean posix api in your case:

```
logs=$(
   printf "%s" "$logs" |
   while IFS= read -r line
   do
      echo "store this to logs"
   done
)
```

Comment: `printf "%s" "$(echo "$logs" | tail -3)"` will show that the last newline is missing.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!. Yes, the last line is missing. I append a newline to variable as workaround. Do you know about better solution?